# Python numpy array manipulation

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

i need to manipulate an numpy array:

My Array has the followng format:

```
x = [1280][720][4]
```

The array stores image data in the third dimension:

```
x[0][0] = [Red,Green,Blue,Alpha]
```

Now i need to manipulate my array to the following form:

```
x = [1280][720]
x[0][0] = Red + Green + Blue / 3
```

My current code is extremly slow and i want to use the numpy array manipulation to speed it up:

```
for a in range(0,719):
    for b in range(0,1279):
        newx[a][b] = x[a][b][0]+x[a][b][1]+x[a][b][2]
x = newx
```

Also, if possible i need the code to work for variable array sizes.

Thansk Alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [numpy.mean](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) function:

```
import numpy as np

n = 1280
m = 720

# Generate a n * m * 4 matrix with random values 
x = np.round(np.random.rand(n, m, 4)*10)

# Calculate the mean value over the first 3 values along the 2nd axix (starting from 0) 
xnew = np.mean(x[:, :, 0:3], axis=2)
```

- `x[:, :, 0:3]` gives you the first 3 values in the 3rd dimension, see: [numpy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)
- `axis=2` specifies, along which axis of the matrix the mean value is calculated.

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there a way to keep my 3 dimensions. So xnew[0][0]=[x] ?

Comment: Use: `xnew_3 = x[:, :, 0:3]`

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I ment to store the mean value in the third dimension. `x[1280,720,1]` @bastelflp

Comment: Resize the first array and overwrite the 3rd dimension with the mean values: `xnew_3 = np.resize(x, (x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 1))` and `xnew_3[:, :, 0] = xnew`

Answer (score 0):

Slice the alpha channel out of the array, and then sum the array along the RGB axis and divide by 3:

```
x = x[:,:,:-1]
x_sum = x.sum(axis=2)
x_div = x_sum / float(3)
```